# css issue with bootstrap menu, even though css matches internet web archive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

recently some css was updated via a template that required me to restore a website. Now, the restore doesn't have the same functionality as it used to. specifically, the css / bootstrap dropdown menu now appears to remain static. You can see the issue on this page here: http://bit.ly/1tDKZEq

I have gone through the different css menus to try and edit the code in firebug but can't seem to fix it, and the template developer isn't any help. The site in question is linked here: http://bit.ly/1tDKZEq

I've compared the css files to the webarchive version of the site, and the css is exactly the same, so I don't know what I am missing...thanks for any help!

Comment: unless it was a pure CSS hover-menu, shouldn't this require some javascript? Maybe you forgot that?

Comment: Also, [I don't think this is the type of question to put on Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).